# DALI DAPC Control not working

Tags: power, led, led-driver, lighting, dali

I am using Osram constant current LED power supply to dimm led lights using DALI.
I have functional program with dimming using DALI DAPC commands.
Dimming in range 100-255 is okay and works as it should but dimming under 100 doesn't do anything,
only when i dimm to power 0 the light shut off.

Is this a limitation of power range in the LED driver, or is it because of the LED lights?

EDIT
Using led driver OPTOTRONIC INTELLIGENT OTi DALI 90/220-240/700 D LT2 L
and 2x LED BOARD 580x24 3100lm In=700mA, Un=30.5V, Pd=21.4W
Control is done through Raspberry Pi Pico and DALI Click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [Osram driver](https://www.osram.com/appsj/pdc/pdf.do?cid=GPS01_3183480&vid=PP_EUROPE_Europe_eCat&lid=EN&mpid=ZMP_4054491) is dimmable down to 1%, which in DAPC terms is 85 (out of 254). DALI [is designed to be](https://www.dali-alliance.org/dali/keyfeatures.html) a log dimming curve so the changes at the lower levels are much smaller than the changes at higher levels, which means that it can be difficult to visually detect the difference between 85 (=0.99%) and 100 (=1.49%).

If you want a wider range, you would have to find a driver than goes down to 0.1% (=DAPC 1).

Comment: I was thinking it might be because of the dimmable range but i didn't know how to quantify it. Thank you for your reply